# how to create json array without keys

Tags: d3.js

```
{"":[{"aprjun":"50","janmar":"31","julsep":"42","octdec":"7","year":"2010"},
{"aprjun":"19","janmar":"6","julsep":"15","octdec":"68","year":"2011"},
{"aprjun":"16","janmar":"4","julsep":"12","octdec":"14","year":"2012"},
{"aprjun":"97","janmar":"9","julsep":"36","octdec":"157","year":"2013"},
{"aprjun":"","janmar":"11","julsep":"","octdec":"","year":"2014"}]}
```

i am having an json array like this which i need to give input to d3js bt i want it like this

```
[{"aprjun":"50","janmar":"31","julsep":"42","octdec":"7","year":"2010"},
{"aprjun":"19","janmar":"6","julsep":"15","octdec":"68","year":"2011"},
{"aprjun":"16","janmar":"4","julsep":"12","octdec":"14","year":"2012"},
{"aprjun":"97","janmar":"9","julsep":"36","octdec":"157","year":"2013"},
{"aprjun":"","janmar":"11","julsep":"","octdec":"","year":"2014"}]
```

how do i get it?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine your json data is like this:

```
var k = {"":[{"aprjun":"50","janmar":"31","julsep":"42","octdec":"7","year":"2010"},{"aprjun":"19","janmar":"6","julsep":"15","octdec":"68","year":"2011"},{"aprjun":"16","janmar":"4","julsep":"12","octdec":"14","year":"2012"},{"aprjun":"97","janmar":"9","julsep":"36","octdec":"157","year":"2013"},{"aprjun":"","janmar":"11","julsep":"","octdec":"","year":"2014"}]}
```

so you need to do : `k[""]` to give you the desired JSON

```
[{"aprjun":"50","janmar":"31","julsep":"42","octdec":"7","year":"2010"},{"aprjun":"19","janmar":"6","julsep":"15","octdec":"68","year":"2011"},{"aprjun":"16","janmar":"4","julsep":"12","octdec":"14","year":"2012"},{"aprjun":"97","janmar":"9","julsep":"36","octdec":"157","year":"2013"},{"aprjun":"","janmar":"11","julsep":"","octdec":"","year":"2014"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array indexing. `for (var i=0; i < 5; i++) { array [i] = {...} }` where 'array' is the name of your variable. Incidentally, why not use the year as a key?